# How to retract an "approved edit"?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was looking into a pending edit request for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823657/playing-random-pairs-of-words-in-sound-arrays), and I was too quick to click "approve".
Is there a way to retract that "approval"?
Or do I have to wait for the system to detect that I am the only approver, and that everybody else disagrees and that I need to be banned from reviewing for X amount of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like @Servy says, you cannot retract your approval; you just have to hope other reviewers will make the correct decision, [which they did](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13867137).

Note that the system won't detect that you're the only one to hit <kbd>Approve</kbd> and you won't get suspended from reviewing for this. ♦ Moderators may investigate the review behaviour of individual users, but a single mistake will usually not be sufficient cause to hand out a review ban. Unless you make a blatantly obvious mistake like approving a spam edit.

Comment: Mods will ban users for a single inappropriate approval in egregious cases, such as approval of spam or clearly abusive content.

Comment: @Servy I was hesitating to add that already, but thanks for noting.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to retract the approval.